# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin Form preview fails with System.Exception - Failed to render Android XAML preview

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am very new to Xamarin.Forms and I am trying to learn using [this tutorial](https://redpillxamarin.com/2016/12/23/202-starting-on-the-right-foot-2/). I have created a blank Xamarin.Forms, Portable Class Library in Visual Studio 2017, running within Windows 10 x64.

I have successfully written, compile and deploy the code from [here](https://redpillxamarin.com/2016/12/23/203-now-for-the-left-foot/) both on emulator and a real Android device. However, I saw that XAML does not get validated at compile time. I have tried to open Forms Previewer, but it fails with:

> System.Exception - Failed to render Android XAML preview

JDK path is correctly set in Xamarin -> Android settings to JDK 64bit: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`

Event Viewer reports this error immediately after the viewer crashes:

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 8.0.1210.13, time stamp: 0x584f5d7e
Faulting module name: libmonosgen-2.0.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5818507d
Exception code: 0x40000015
Fault offset: 0x00000000002c96a1
Faulting process id: 0x4d28
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2a6c1cdfa70e9
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\libmonosgen-2.0.dll
Report Id: 3562b40a-403a-416a-9531-e7c357aae7d6
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Installed components**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
Version 15.0.26228.9 D15RTWSVC
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Installed Version: Community

Xamarin   4.3.0.784 (73f58d6)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android SDK   7.1.0.41 (9578cdc)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   10.4.0.123 (35d1ccd)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
```

**Question: how can I overcome this error?**

**[EDIT]**

Xamarin's bug tracking system seems to have [something about this error](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=53163), but the information is not accessible (even if I have an account):

> Bug 53163
>
> You are not allowed to view this bug.

Comment: Go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings, you should see 3 green checkoxes if not then you missing android components

Comment: Yes, I can see the green checkboxes for `JDK (1.8.0)`, `Android SDK Location (Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)` and `Android NDK Location (ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b)`.

Comment: Try also updating the xamarin Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Check now and then install if there is any update, also try clean, build, delete obj and bin folder, restart visual studio.

Comment: Xamarin -> Other is missing from the Options (I think it exists in VS2015, but not in VS2017). I have rebuilt (which performs a clean) + restart VS, but I have the same problem. From Event viewer, it looks related to `libmonosgen-2.0.dll` library, but I do not know how to approach. Google shows me a result from Xamarin forums, but I am not allowed to see page content (although I have an account there).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `Almis`' suggestion and a little break from programming, I have managed to overcome this error:

1. I have entered VS2015 (which was already installed before installing VS2017) and created an empty Xamarin.Forms project
2. VS2015 offered to upgrade Xamarin and accepted. Also, upgraded all other components offered in `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other` (stable)
3. (sanity check) VS2015 Xamarin Form Preview works
4. Reopening VS2017 and opening Xamarin Form Preview work correctly